# Removing .htaccess Authentication Restrictions

Tags: apache, authentication, .htaccess

I have a project that has .htaccess Authentication but i want to remove it for a certain assets folder.

i tried adding a htaccess in that folder with :

```
AuthType none
Satisfy Any

Allow from All
Order Allow, Deny
```

but it doesnt seem to work :(
Any thought on this. Thank you so much

**Edit**
The directory i am trying to unprotect is not a real directory, but a rewrite rule.
I dont have access to httpd.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your full .htaccess I'm guessing, but what about something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^assets/ - [E=allow-assets:1]
Allow from env=allow-assets
```

That could go in the .htaccess of the parent directory, not assets.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do this if you have access to /etc/httpd.conf -- do you?